# mockito is not working in my gradle project

Tags: java, groovy, mockito, dependencies, build.gradle

I tried to use mock to replace the input of a file to my code

```
package bitmap.transformer;

import org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.C;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Bitmap {
    private static Path outputPath;
    private static BufferedImage imageData;
    private static BufferedImage newImage;
    private static   BufferedImage outputImage;
    public static int width , height;

    public Bitmap(String filePath , String outputPath) throws IOException {
        outputPath = String.valueOf(Paths.get(outputPath));
//        Path convertToPath = Paths.get(filePath);
        imageData = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
        height = imageData.getHeight();
        width = imageData.getWidth();
    }
    public void flipVertically() {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height / 2; y++) {
                int topColor = imageData.getRGB(x, y);
                int bottomColor = imageData.getRGB(x, height - 1 - y);
                imageData.setRGB(x, y, bottomColor);
                imageData.setRGB(x, height - 1 - y, topColor);
            }
        }
    }
    public  void stretchVertically() {
        int heightM = (height * 2);
        newImage = new BufferedImage(width, heightM, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < heightM; y++) {
                int color = imageData.getRGB(x, y / 2);

                newImage.setRGB(x, y, color);
                y++;
                if (y != heightM) {
                    newImage.setRGB(x, y, color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public  void random() {
        int rgb;
        for (int y = 1; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 1; x < width; x++) {
                rgb = imageData.getRGB(x, y) / 2;
                imageData.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }
    }
    public  void reverseBlackAndGreen() {
        Color black = new Color(0,0,0);
        Color white = new Color(255,255,255);
        Color green = new Color(46,255,0);


        for (int x = 0; x<width ; x++) {
            for (int y =0 ; y<height;y++){
//                int color = imageData.getRGB(x,y);
                Color color = new Color(imageData.getRGB(x,y));
                if(color.getRed() == 0 && color.getGreen() == 0 && color.getBlue() == 0){
                    imageData.setRGB(x,y,green.getRGB());
                } else  {
                    imageData.setRGB(x,y,black.getRGB());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public  void setImageData(BufferedImage image, String outputPath) {
        imageData = image;
        outputPath = String.valueOf(Paths.get(outputPath));
    }
    public void save(String outputPath) {
        try {
            File file = new File(outputPath);
            ImageIO.write(imageData, "bmp", file);
            System.out.println("Image saved to: " + file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to test it , I add mockito to my dependencies but it still doesn't work

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import bitmap.transformer.Bitmap;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Color;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class BitmapTest {

    private BufferedImage mockImage;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
       try {
           mockImage = mock(BufferedImage.class);
           bitmap = new Bitmap(mockImage, "outputPath"); // Use a valid output path here


        mockImage = new BufferedImage(3, 3, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        mockImage.setRGB(0, 0, Color.RED.getRGB());
        mockImage.setRGB(0, 1, Color.GREEN.getRGB());
        mockImage.setRGB(0, 2, Color.BLUE.getRGB());
        mockImage.setRGB(1, 0, Color.YELLOW.getRGB());
        mockImage.setRGB(1, 1, Color.CYAN.getRGB());
        mockImage.setRGB(1, 2, Color.MAGENTA.getRGB());
        mockImage.setRGB(2, 0, Color.BLACK.getRGB());
        mockImage.setRGB(2, 1, Color.WHITE.getRGB());
        mockImage.setRGB(2, 2, Color.GRAY.getRGB());
        bitmap = new Bitmap(mockImage, "outputPath"); // Use a valid output path here
       } catch (IOException e){
           System.out.println(e);
       }
    }

        @Test
        public void testFlipVertically() {
            bitmap.flipVertically();
            assertEquals(Color.GRAY.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 0));
            assertEquals(Color.WHITE.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 1));
            assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 2));
            assertEquals(Color.MAGENTA.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 0));
            assertEquals(Color.CYAN.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 1));
            assertEquals(Color.YELLOW.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 2));
            assertEquals(Color.BLUE.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 0));
            assertEquals(Color.GREEN.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 1));
            assertEquals(Color.RED.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 2));
        }

    @Test
        public void testStretchVertically() {
            bitmap.stretchVertically();

            assertEquals(Color.RED.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 0));
            assertEquals(Color.RED.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 1));
            assertEquals(Color.GREEN.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 2));
            assertEquals(Color.GREEN.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 3));
            assertEquals(Color.BLUE.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 0));
            assertEquals(Color.BLUE.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 1));
            assertEquals(Color.YELLOW.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 2));
            assertEquals(Color.YELLOW.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 3));
            assertEquals(Color.MAGENTA.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 0));
            assertEquals(Color.MAGENTA.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 1));
            assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 2));
            assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 3));
        }


        @Test
        public void testRandom() {
            BufferedImage originalImage = new BufferedImage(mockImage.getWidth(), mockImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            originalImage.setData(mockImage.getData());

            bitmap.random();

            assertNotEquals(originalImage, mockImage);
        }

    public void setUp() {
        try {
            mockImage = new BufferedImage(3, 3, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            mockImage.setRGB(0, 0, Color.RED.getRGB());
            mockImage.setRGB(0, 1, Color.GREEN.getRGB());
            mockImage.setRGB(0, 2, Color.BLUE.getRGB());
            mockImage.setRGB(1, 0, Color.YELLOW.getRGB());
            mockImage.setRGB(1, 1, Color.CYAN.getRGB());
            mockImage.setRGB(1, 2, Color.MAGENTA.getRGB());
            mockImage.setRGB(2, 0, Color.BLACK.getRGB());
            mockImage.setRGB(2, 1, Color.WHITE.getRGB());
            mockImage.setRGB(2, 2, Color.GRAY.getRGB());
            bitmap = new Bitmap(mockImage, "outputPath"); // Use a valid output path here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testReverseBlackAndGreen() {
        bitmap.reverseBlackAndGreen();

        assertEquals(Color.GREEN.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 0));
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 1));
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(0, 2));
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 0));
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 1));
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(1, 2));
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 0));
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 1));
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK.getRGB(), mockImage.getRGB(2, 2));
    }




}
```

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details on building Java & JVM projects, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '5.4.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core

}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'bitmap.transformer.App'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I would be truly thankful if you would help me

a solution for the problem I'm facing
I sync gradle , I checked it's not set to offline , I don't think there is any conflict with any other dependency  though I'm not sure , there is no throwing error since I'm using mock , I think , my gradle version is the latest since I already checked for updates before I started this project this morning  , and I've added it to build.gradle

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).